# .NET Ping() giving false timeouts?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, ping

I have a script that is looping through and sending a ping to a host every second. The purpose of which is to test wireless performance on my home network. The issue is, I seem to be getting timeouts from my script, while a standard "ping  -t" on either client (pingER and pingEE) have no such timeouts. In fact, not once in the last 30 minutes has either timed out, while my script has received timeout replies every few minutes.

My essential script is below. In all cases, when it does happen, my reply is TimedOut with a response time of 0ms. Is my script causing false timeouts? Thanks.

EDIT: updated code to reflect newest changes, still having same behavior.

```
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    hosts.ForEach(h =>
    {
        var buffer = new byte[32];
        var reply = ping.Send(h, 4000, buffer, new PingOptions(600, true));
        var error = reply.Status != IPStatus.Success || reply.RoundtripTime > maxRoundTrip;

        if (verbose || error)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}: {1} ({2}ms)", h, reply.Status, reply.RoundtripTime);
            builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            if (error)
            {
                WriteLog(h, reply);
                SendEmail(h, reply);
            }
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Which error condition is failing? 1000 ms for the reply should be long enough, but is there a particular reason you aren't just using the standard ping?

Comment: I'm using this as I wanted to let it run and alert me and log if there are errors. However, it doesn't seem as reliable in my case, or I'm doing something wrong. Running a CMD ping.exe on the same machines gives me no timeouts whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have figured it out. I was using the netbios name for the machine in question. I'm guessing that each time it did a ping, it was factoring in the IP lookup in the round trip and was timing out. When I used just the IP, it worked just fine and hasn't timed out.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: may I know how you use the define netbios name in C#? or can you show me how you define the `h` in your program? thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!  Yea that makes sense, since the `ping -t` only did the nslookup once before the first ping, but the .NET code would've been doing the lookup on each iteration (unless there was some sort of DNS caching going on behind the scenes).  @V-SHY, by "netbios" name, he just meant he was using FQDN instead of IP address; and the `h` is defined as the first variable in the `ForEach` lamda expression.

Answer (score 2):

If your `ping -t` timeout value is less than 1000 or the value of `maxRoundTrip` is less than 1000 then you are checking against different timeouts in your two different pings (.NET `Ping.Send` vs. `ping -t`). The default Windows ping timeout is 4000 ms. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490968.aspx

Also in your .NET code, you are sending the max buffer size of 65500 bytes. The default Windows ping command sends only 32 bytes of data.

So the difference between either the timeout or buffer size is likely what is causing the variance.

More info about the .NET Ping.Send method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144956(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I decreased the buffer to 32 bytes and increased the timeout to 4000ms, but still getting timeouts at the same frequency.

Comment: What options are you using for the `ping -t` command that you are comparing to? And what type of application are you running the .NET `Ping.Send` in (website/IIS, command line tool, WinForms)? If IIS, then you could check application pool recycle time.

Comment: Also what version of .NET are you using? And did you increase both the `ping.send` timeout and the `maxRoundTrip` timeout values?

Comment: CMD ping is just "ping <host> -t". The app is a c# 4.5 console app running on my desktop machine. I get the same results when running it from other machines.

Comment: Ping status is TimedOut. I tried your suggestion, still getting the random timeouts. Also, I've had a standard CMD ping running at the same time for over an hour now without a single timeout.

Comment: During the timeouts from the .NET app, are the Windows `ping -t` results anywhere close to 4000 ms (could be a few ms diff b/t while .NET overhead processes the ping response)? I noticed the max TTL for Windows ping is 255 and "normal" is 128. Could also try chaning .NET `new PingOptions(128, true)`, and adding `-w 4000 -i 128 -l 32` to your Windows pings to make sure they line up w/ the options used in .NET code.

Comment: I will try that. When the timeouts did occur in the .NET script, my ping.exe -t on both machines were regular and had no spikes. I.e., there were no fluctuations. The only fluctuations that occurred were when windows periodically rescans wireless networks over minute or so (this was consistent).

Comment: OK. I have since tried that and am still getting the same issue. Here's a screenshot of everything, including the code, the result of MY script (showing a timeout right as I took the screenshot), and the ping.exe (with your command suggestion). As you see, it times out and there is no fluctuation in the ping.exe. IMAGE: http://i.imgur.com/ZOwnX7a.png

Comment: Also, it always seems to be the wireless laptop that is timing out. Now, this would make sense if both ping.exe AND my script were timing out, but only my script is. Ping.exe has not had a timeout yet, and I've been letting it runs for hours.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the byte array size is the main reason (I programmed a similar ping application)

When

```
var buffer = new byte[65500];
```

> 2014/3/30 11:29:26
>   8.8.8.8: TimedOut (0ms)

changed to

```
var buffer = new byte[32];
```

> 2014/3/30 11:32:50
>   8.8.8.8: Success (8ms)

I deduced that the ping buffer if too high then the ICMP echo message might be fragmented become more than one packets then only send out,therefore it cannot completed the ping within the timeout period. (But seem like OP mentioned in answer it is hostname resolve problem, then may be my deduction is wrong)

my sample code

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int delay = 1000;
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            //OP using something else?
            System.Net.IPAddress h = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");

            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                    //change buffer size change the result...
                    //var buffer = new byte[65500];
                    var buffer = new byte[32];
                    var reply = ping.Send(h, 1000, buffer, new PingOptions(600, false));
                    var error = reply.Status != IPStatus.Success || reply.RoundtripTime > 3000;

                    if (error)
                    {
                        builder.AppendFormat("{0}: {1} ({2}ms)", h, reply.Status, reply.RoundtripTime);
                        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.AppendFormat("{0}: {1} ({2}ms)", h, reply.Status, reply.RoundtripTime);
                    }

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var reply = ping.Send(h, 1000, buffer, new PingOptions(600, false));
```

1000 is timeout (ms) for the ping reply...

Comment: "delay" is set to 1000ms. The timeout on the Send call I've varied and had the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior as the OP.  My ping.Send() is only sending a buffer of byte[30] and always uses the explicit IP so no DNS/NetBIOS involved.  I've tried varying timeout values but consistently see regular timeout returns from Send() vs zero timeouts when using ping from the command-line.

```
public PingCheck(string address, int timeout = 250, int pingNbr = 1)
{
    var rtn = IPAddress.TryParse(address, out IPAddress addr);
    if (rtn)
    {
        IpAddress = addr;

        var dataSend = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        var pinger = new Ping();
        var pingerOptions = new PingOptions();
        pingerOptions.DontFragment = true;
        var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataSend);

        var statusList = new List<IPStatus>();
        var lossList = new List<bool>();
        var tripList = new List<long>();

        for (int i=0; i<pingNbr; i++)
        {
            var pingerReply = pinger.Send(addr, timeout, buffer, pingerOptions);
            var bufback = pingerReply.Buffer;
            var dataBack = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufback);

            var status = pingerReply.Status;
            var loss = (dataSend != dataBack);
            var msecs = pingerReply.RoundtripTime;

            statusList.Add(status);
            lossList.Add(loss);
            tripList.Add(msecs);
        }

       // TODO: Add statistics check
    }
    else
        throw new PingException("No IP Address");
}
```